# Add class active to multiple divs based on select value

Tags: jquery

I already have the base functionality set up for this but need to modify it slightly and I am stumped. My current code adds an 'active' class to one div based on the value of a select dropdown. What I need to do is add the class active to multiple divs based on multiple values in the select.

Right now if the select value equals '.recs' the div with the class 'recs' receives class 'active' on change of the select. What I need to do is: If the select value has multiple values such as ".recs .green .rep" then add class 'active' to all divs with the class recs, green, or rep.

My current code follows:

jQuery:

```
$("select[name='wayfinding-select']").change(function(){
  select_changed();
});

function select_changed(){
jQuery("a[class*='wayfinding-btn']").each(function(){
   jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
});
jQuery("select[name='wayfinding-select']").each(function(){
    var selected = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(selected).addClass('active');
    console.log(selected);
});
}
```

Markup:

```
<select name="wayfinding-select" class="form-control form-group wayfinding-select">
<option value=".recs .green .rep">
    Add class active to all 3 divs
</option>
<option value=".recs">
    Add class active to RECs div only
</option>
<option value=".recs .green">
    Add class active to RECs and Green divs
</option>
</select>

<div class="wayfinding-btn recs">Renewable Energy Certificates</div>
<div class="wayfinding-btn green">Green Programs</div>
<div class="wayfinding-btn rep">Renewable Energy Procurement</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You mean like that : https://jsfiddle.net/2a6o06wh/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you create an array with the classes of the selected value

```
var selected = $(this).val();
selected = selected.split(" ");
```

Second, you join them in a string separated by comma to get all classes in a string separated with comma.

```
selected = selected.join(',');
```

Third, you use the string as a jquery selector to add the class

```
$(selected).addClass("active"); //for example $(".recs,.green").addClass("active")
```

Comment: Ah nice, your solution seems to require less work. @Jose, doesn't the join function automatically delimit values using a comma if an argument isn't provided?

Comment: @sm1215 yes it does. I rejected the edit but Castillo approved it. I guess it is easier for new comers to understand it that way. I also don't know if all browsers act the same and use a comma by default.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp if he separator is omitted, the elements are separated with a comma

Comment: Thanks all, very helpful!

Comment: I suppose, yeah it could be considered good practice to specify one

Comment: Just on a side note, it seem like it is faster to use replace instead of split/join : http://jsperf.com/split-vs-replace-in-string/2. I though it was interesting to know.

Comment: I didn't read the documentation for join function. Good to know it. Sorry for the edit but noob people like me will understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the split function. This will cause an an array to be returned to the selected variable and then you can just use the $.each function to iterate over whatever values happen to be in the selected array.

It would look like this:

```
jQuery("select[name='wayfinding-select']").each(function() {
    var selected = jQuery(this).val().split(' ');
    $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
        jQuery(value).addClass('active');
    });
    console.log(selected);
});
```

Also, noticed the section of code responsible for resetting the classes was targeting an anchor instead of a div. I changed this so the jsfiddle would work correctly, but not sure if you had plans to switch your divs over to anchors in the future.

In any case, here's an updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/z75tom8v/