# Add class="active" to multiple divs based on two dropdowns

Tags: html, jquery, css, split

Pretend I'm running a machine shop. I have multiple employees in a set of defined job categories. Their job category defines areas of the shop each employee may have access to.

Employees may be assigned to one or two job categories, and some areas are accessible to all job categories.

I want to visualize this using a select box for each job category, and a set of possible access areas which will be highlighted in green if the employee meets the job category requirements.

I stumbled across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160924/add-class-active-to-multiple-divs-based-on-select-value) and it works perfectly when applied to only one job category. However, once I added a second select box and tried to apply the same solution to the second select box, the first dropdown stopped working entirely.

Here's the code I'm working with now:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RFox1981/kd1uahsL/2/)

HTML:

```
    <div name="jobs-div" id="jobs-div">
        <p>Assign Jobs:</p>
        <div name="jobs" id="jobs">
            <div name="job1-dropdown" id="job1-dropdown">
                <label for="job1">Job 1:</label>
                <select name="job1" id="job1">
                    <option selected="selected" value="default">None</option>
                    <option value=".mgr">Manager</option>
                    <option value=".sl">Shift Lead</option>
                    <option value=".fd">Front Desk</option>
                    <option value=".wld">Welder</option>
                    <option value=".mac">Machinist</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div name="job2-dropdown" id="job2-dropdown">
                <label for="job2">Job 2:</label>
                <select name="job2" id="job2">
                    <option selected="selected" value="default">None</option>
                    <option value=".mgr">Manager</option>
                    <option value=".sl">Shift Lead</option>
                    <option value=".fd">Front Desk</option>
                    <option value=".wld">Welder</option>
                    <option value=".mac">Machinist</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="access all-jobs" name="brk-rm" id="brk-rm">Break Room</div>
    <div class="access all-jobs" name="first-aid" id="first-aid">First Aid Station</div>
    <div class="access wld" name="wld-cab" id="wld-cab">Welding Equipment</div>
    <div class="access mgr sl fd" name="cash-reg" id="cash-reg">Cash Register</div>
    <div class="access mgr sl" name="clean" id="clean">Cleaning Supplies</div>
    <div class="access sl mac" name="mach-st" id="mach-st">Machine Stations</div>
    <div class="access mgr sl" name="keys" id="keys">Shop Keys</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .all-jobs {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        color: black;
    }

    .access-enabled {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        color: black;
    }
```

JS:

```
    $("select[name='job1']").change(function() {
        select_changed();
    });

    function select_changed() {
        jQuery("div[class*='access']").each(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('access-enabled');
            console.log(this);
        });
        jQuery("select[name='job1']").each(function() {
            var selected = jQuery(this).val().split(' ');
            $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
                jQuery(value).addClass('access-enabled');
            });
            console.log(selected);
        });
    }
        
    $("select[name='job2']").change(function() {
        select_changed();
    });

    function select_changed() {
        jQuery("div[class*='access']").each(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('access-enabled');
            console.log(this);
        });
        jQuery("select[name='job2']").each(function() {
            var selected = jQuery(this).val().split(' ');
            $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
                jQuery(value).addClass('access-enabled');
            });
            console.log(selected);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `function select_changed() { ... }` twice, which is not allowed.

Change the second assignment to

```js
    $("select[name='job2']").change(function() {
        select_changed2();
    });

    function select_changed2() { ... }
```

Include [jQuery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js) in the Fiddle and it will run.

Comment: Thanks! I figured I was overlooking something silly. I've updated the fiddle and it's working now. However, I want both job classes to run concurrently.

Example: If I select Welder for job 1 and Machinist for job 2, both Welder and Machinist should end up highlighted. I'm sure my issue is because both functions are removing access-enabled before applying it to the applicable job classes, however I don't want to do something like set job 1 to Manager, then set job 1 to something else and still have the Manager classes highlighted before I go to select job 2.

Comment: @RFox1981, this is not how SO work, I'm afraid. It is not a chat where you can build on your question indefinately by commenting or changing the question. Nor is it meant for posting software development assignments. 'Accept' your current issue to be solved and post the above comment as a new question if you must, one issue at a time. Make sure you try to develop it yourself, as people will (again) ask for your code trials.